# Python: Ignore a # / and random numbers in a string

Tags: python, enumerate

I use part of code to read a website and scrap some information and place it into Google and print some directions.

I'm having an issue as some of the information. the site i use sometimes adds a # followed by 3 random numbers then a / and another 3 numbers e.g #037/100

how can i use python to ignore this "#037/100" string?

I currently use

```
for i, part in enumerate(list(addr_p)):
        if '#' in part:
                del addr_p[i]
                break
```

to remove the # if found but I'm not sure how to do it for the random numbers

Any ideas ?

Comment: You want to remove `@` from the words or remove words from the lists if they have `@`?

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear, I editet it to something with more sense. He already had code to remove the # or @ but not the random numbers and the / after that.

Comment: @BeowulfOF I am not sure if the edit is correct. We might want to wait for the OP to respond :)

Comment: For the record, it is a bad idea to remove items from the list while iterating it.

Comment: Ok so here is the string

Comment: Ok so here is the string INC0157 16/01/14 20:11 RESPOND PRIVATE ALARM, ALARM LEVEL: 1, : @ A SCHOOL #347/157  BARLEY RD  LINCOLN,MAP:PLO 2 K12,=INFORMATION HERE. So my question is my above command removes the @sign but now i need to remove the #347/157. The numbers will always change but the # and / will always be in same place in sting. The above command deletes  the @ from the string and that's what i would like to do with other part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you find yourself wanting to remove "three digits followed by a forward slash followed by three digits" from a string `s`, you could do

```
import re
s = "this is a string #123/234 with other stuff"
t = re.sub('#\d{3}\/\d{3}', '', s)
print t
```

Result:

```
'this is a string  with other stuff'
```

Explanation:

```
#    - literal character '#'
\d{3} - exactly three digits
\/    - forward slash (escaped since it can have special meaning)
\d{3} - exactly three digits
```

And the whole thing that matches the above (if it's present) is replaced with '' - i.e. "removed".

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

re.sub('#[0-9]+\/[0-9]+$', '', addr_p[i])
```

I'm no wizzard with regular expressions but i'd imagine you could so something like this.
You could even handle '@' in the regexp as well.

Comment: I think the second [0-9]+ pattern should be removed, since he want to keep the end of the string

Comment: I don't think so, *"then a / and **another 3 numbers** e.g #037/100"*

Comment: i'm not convinced i'm right tho, hehe. But i just thought he wanted to scrap both random numbers. We'll see :)

Comment: You need to escape the forward slash... `'#\d+\/\d+$` would mean "the hash sign followed by digits followed by a forward slash followed by digits until the end of the string"

Comment: You're correct @Floris, i'll keep the [0-9] for intuitive purposes tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd double your problems and match against a regular expression for this.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'([\w\s]+)#\d+\/\d+([\w\s]+)')
m = regex.match('This is a string with a #123/987 in it')
if m: 
    s = m.group(1) + m.group(2)
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same, then you could check if the line starts with a #, then set the string to itself without the first 8 characters.

if part[0:1] == '#':
     part = part[8:]

if the first letter is a #, it sets the string to itself, from the 8th character to the end.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way:

```
import re
s = "this is a string #123/234 with other stuff"
t = re.sub(r'#\S+', '', s)
print(t)
```